# Using Android Loader while retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, loader

I am retrieving data from Firebase and use this data to present some information. Since retrieving data takes time I put a CountDownTimer to make the app wait but it is not a nice solution and it does not look good. I found that Android Loader can do this job but I could not make it work. Can anyone solve this?

Here is the code I use to get data from Firebase.

```
infoReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { //inforeference is DatabaseReference
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            try {
                Info info = postSnapshot.getValue(Info.class);
                    infoList.add(info); //Just an arraylist
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise using a Loader with Firebase.  There's no real advantage.  Just register a listener when you need it (activity onStart), then unregister when the activity is going away (onStop).  On orientation change, just register the listener again - it will pick up anything that was read last time from cache.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example? I cannot make it work. I tried an .addOnCompleteListener

Comment: There's plenty of sample code and codelabs out there that demonstrate how to use Firebase on Android.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doSomething();
        }
    },2000);
```

right after retrieving data from firebase,yet not a very good idea. looking for solution too.